# How do I get to the menu in Emacs in console mode?

Tags: emacs

If you launch Emacs using the `-nw` flag to force a console session (rather than an X session if you have X windows running), how do you get to the menu?

There are some items held in the menus that are infrequently-enough used on my part that I don't recall the escape or control sequence to do them.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`M-x menu-bar-open`, which is usually bound to `F10`. This works with and without `menu-bar-mode` (which just shows the names of the menus at the top of the screen).

Comment: Also, in case you're on Mac and have F10 bound to Expose, you can use Ctrl+F10 to get the same effect. Tested with a vanilla install of Emacs 23 from homebrew.

Comment: But, this way, we can not display menu bar of special buffer mode, isn't ?
That is, in SVN buffer, we can not open SVN menu.

Comment: @swdev - This is my experience too.

Comment: F10 works  in 2021 with Emacs 27.1 ([built from source](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/11/11/building-emacs-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04/)) on Linux ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment))).

Answer (score 16):

On my computer (with [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE)), it is not <kbd>F10</kbd> but M-` which allows to access menu items. More information is available here:

http://linux.about.com/od/emacs_doc/a/emacsdoc317.htm

Comment: Worked on my Mac terminal and opens in a new buffer where you use simple key commands to move around and go to the menu items you want. e.g., `3`

Comment: M-` calls tmm-menubar (text-mode-menu), which shows the menu options in a buffer, while F10 calls menu-bar-open, which lets you navigate the menubar in place. But if the menubar is off, F10 runs tmm-menubar.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 7):

The <kbd>F10</kbd> key will access the menus for me in both Windows versions and a console version in [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (RHEL) 4.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>F10</kbd> is inaccessible for ssh to a remote host over a Mac terminal.

How to get to the menu:

<kbd>C-h b to get all the key bindings.</kbd>

Use <kbd>C-s</kbd> to incrementally search on "menu" in the key
bindings help. Hit <kbd>C-s</kbd> to find next and next occurrences.

See the <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd>?

Type <kbd>ESC</kbd> ` on the Mac and it will work.

Answer (score 5):

[***La Carte***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte) (library [lacarte.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/lacarte.el)) --------

It lets you execute menu commands from the keyboard, using completion:

```
ESC M-x
Menu command:
Menu command: t [TAB]
Menu command: Tools > 
Menu command: Tools > Compa [TAB]
Menu command: Tools > Compare (Ediff) > Two F [TAB]
Menu command: Tools > Compare (Ediff) > Two Files... [RET]
```

Answer (score 4):

For my Emacs and Mac setup, I found that <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> creates a buffer showing Emacs menu-content selectable by a further keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

```
M-x menu-bar-mode
```

Comment: That looks like it turns the menu on and off